# How to make a list of dataframe from a given list with specific headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am tyring to `group by` on column `brands` in a `dataframe` where a `column` carrier is equal to a string `DHL` :

main_df:

```
Carrier,brand,store,order_id,tracking_id
DHL,HP,UK,2722,67920
USP,HP,UK,2918,17820
DHL,HP,US,2122,47920
DHL,DELL,SG,17229,75127
USP,HP,UK,2908,67820
DHL,DELL,UK,2201,24520
```

I am trying to get this output(splitting on column 'brands') :

split_df1:

```
DHL,HP,UK,2722,67920
DHL,HP,US,2122,47920
```

split_df2:

```
DHL,DELL,SG,17229,75127
DHL,DELL,UK,2201,24520
```

this is my code

```
def split_csv():
    print(base_path)
    tracking_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_path,tracking_ids_csv))
    carrier_split_df = tracking_df.loc[tracking_df['Carrier']=='DHL']
    headers = carrier_split_df.columns.tolist()
    print(headers)
    brand_split_df = [index[1] for index in carrier_split_df.groupby(['brand'])] 
    for i in range(len(brand_split_df)): # This gives me a list
        print(brand_split_df[i])
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(brand_split_df)):
        df[i] = pd.DataFrame(brand_split_df[i],columns=headers) # error here
    return df[i]
```

this `for loop` gives me the correct output, but its in a `list`,
how do i make this list into separate `dataframes` ?

```
for i in range(len(brand_split_df)): # This gives me a list
        print(brand_split_df[i])
```

output:

split_df1:

```
DHL,HP,UK,2722,67920
DHL,HP,US,2122,47920
```

split_df2:

```
DHL,DELL,SG,17229,75127
DHL,DELL,UK,2201,24520
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you group the selection, extract the groups with list comprehension:

```
groups = df[df.Carrier=='DHL'].groupby('brand')
df1, df2 = [group for _,group in groups]
```

Or perhaps you may want to have a dictionary of dataframes instead of the two variables:

```
d = {key: group for key,group in groups}
```

Comment: `groups = df[df.Carrier=='DHL'].groupby('brand') : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Carrier'`

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is in the line

```
df[i] = pd.DataFrame(brand_split_df[i],columns=headers) # error here
```

which is due to df being a dataframe, you actually need df[i] to be dataframes

```
# df = pd.DataFrame() # wrong
df=[pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame()] # what will solve the error
```

Suggesting from

> I am tyring to group by on column brands in a dataframe where a column carrier is equal to a string DHL :

I think you just need a dataframe which has only `DHL` and sorted by `brand`

```
def split_csv():
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    new_df=df[df['Carrier']=="DHL"].sort_values(by=['brand'])
    return new_df.reset_index().drop(['index'],axis=1)
```

I hope this is what you want!

Edit: if it's the dataframe split then it's in @DYZ's answer

Comment: i need to split the dataframe into two DELL and HP, where DHL carrier is constant